# LinearLayout align Textviews using weight parameter

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code which is a row layout for a list view i have. I would like the labels to the left and the data to the right. The data should be aligned by the left side but at the moment it looks crooked.

I have tried to specify a weight for the textviews in the linearlayout. the label has weight 1 and the data has weight 5. I expected that the data textviews would be lined up vertically as they should take up 5/6 of the horizontal width, leaving 1/6 for the label.

why are the data TextViews not equally taking up the same amount of screen width?

In the developers options i have checked the show layout boundaries and it proves that the data textviews do not line up vertically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"

    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotypelabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Type: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"

                      />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotype"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="5"

                      />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfosurnamelabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"

                      />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfosurname"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                     android:layout_below="@id/carerinfotypelabel"
                     />


        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

                   <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfoaddresslabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Address: "
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                          />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfoaddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_weight="5" />


        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfopostcodelabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Postcode: "
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                          />

                     <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfopostcode"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_weight="5" />

        </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                     <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfomobilelabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mobile: "
                         android:layout_weight="1"
                         android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                          />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfomobile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"

                          />


        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinfotelhomelabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Tel: "
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
              />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinfotelhome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"

              />

        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotelno1label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tel 1: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                     />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotelno1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_weight="5" />


        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotel2label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Tel 2: "
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                     />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotel2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                     />

        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotel3label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="Tel 3: "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/carerinfotel3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"/>


        </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfotel4label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tel 4: "
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"/>




                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/carerinfotel4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5" />


        </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carerinforelationshiplabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Relationship: "
                        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
        />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinforelationship"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="5"
            />

        </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/carerinfodoblabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DOB: "
                        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
        />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinfodob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="5"
            />



        </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


                           <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carerinfopinlabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:text="PIN: "
                               android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/cf_blue"
                             />


                           <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/carerinfopin"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                               android:layout_weight="5"
                             />


     </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because of `wrap_content`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to specify android:weightSum="6" in all of your horizontal layout.
This property tells android to separate container in 6 parts, then with android:layout_weight you tell to android how many parts one element must fit.

Another thing: when you set android:layout_weight you must set 0dp on corresponding width or height property. Otherwise it may go wrong

So an example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinfodoblabel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DOB: "
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/cf_blue" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/carerinfodob"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for what the OP is asking, `0dp` as width is the correct answer, but it is by no means mandatory. There are many cases where setting `wrap_content` or a fixed value is perfectly valid.

Comment: @njzk2 how can a fixed value work with layout_weigth?

Comment: @firegloves Thanks, i didn't use the weightSum and it works great

Comment: @firegloves one has to understand how weights work: first the mandatory value set by `layout_width` is attributed (so for example, one view can request `42dp`), then the remaining width is shared based on the weight. In this case, it is distributed 1/6 and 5/6 of the remaining, which is the entire width, because both views have `0dp`. But if each requests some measure first, the final distribution changes. That's why using `wrap_content` with a weight is not invalid, only less predictable in result.

Answer (score 0):

Every subrow's left textviews are not aligning up because of `layout_width="wrap_content"`. They all take up space according to their content first, after which more space is provided by `weight` property which can vary too. The `layout_weight` property is used to instruct how the remaining space if left to be used among the views of `LinearLayout`. You can do two things here.

Either make `layout_width` of both textviews as `0dp` for every subrow. This means whole of width is remaining space and calculation of giving space is done by `weight` only for every subrow which will be consistent.

Or you can manually define `width` of every textview as equal (for eg `40dp`).